# Why is this allowed?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, overloading

So I know it is disallowed to have functions with the same parameters and names:

```
int a(int b) {
    return b;
}
int a(int b) {
    return b;
}

int main() {
    int c = a(4);
}
```

This above won't compile. But then I got thinking, what if I passed one by reference, and one by value?

```
int a(int b) {
    return b;
}
int a(int& b) {
    return b;
}

int main() {
    int c = a(4);
}
```

The above does compile, I guess because you can't pass `4` to by reference, so it assumes you want the first `a`, which means the compiler can distinguish which function you want to call. If I then change `main` to this:

```
int main() {
    int c = a(4);
    a(c);
}
```

It will fail to compile, I assume because `c` can be passed to either function, so the compiler doesn't know which function to call.

But what about... THIS?

```
int a(const int& b) {
    return b;
}
int a(int& b) {
    return b;
}

int main() {
    int c = a(4);
    a(c);
}
```

This does compile. Why? I expected it to not, because `c` can be passed to both the first and second `a`. Is there some misconception I have?

My question specifically is, how come this (code below) does not compile, and the final one does?

```
int a(int b) {
    return b;
}
int a(int& b) {
    return b;
}

int main() {
    int c = a(4);
    a(c);
}
```

If I was the compiler, and I could choose which function to call based how close the parameters matched, for the call `a(c)`, I could choose from both the first and second. Is there any reason that the first or second `a` cannot be chosen from in this example?

Comment: One of those is a perfect match; the other isn't.

Comment: @chris So the compiler just guesses?

Comment: No, it uses the perfect match.

Comment: @chris ok, I understand. But why doesn't the second code chunk (with modified main) compile? Because there are two perfect matches? What exactly constitutes a perfect match in the first place?

Comment: @BWG you mean the third? the second does compile

Comment: @BWG, STL did a great video on this topic. [Here you go!](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-Cpp-3-of-n)

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl Second one does not compile for me (visual studio 2013)

Comment: @BWG yes, I mixed them up.

Comment: @chris Thank you, I will watch it. Also question edited.

Comment: The first `a(c)` version does not compile because it is ambiguous as to which function it should pass to. Passing `int c` by copy (`a(int b)`) is equally valid as passing it by reference (`a(int& b)`), so the compiler cannot resolve the tie and throws an error. Unlike the `a(int const & b)` conversion in your final example, which is explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The process of choosing the correct function to use from a function call is called *Overload Resolution*. When a function is called, the compiler searches for all functions with that name (overloads) and compiles them into an *overload set*. Simply put, a best match is chosen by picking the functions that require the least conversions as possible from their parameters.

These are the two functions compiler chooses from `a(c)`:

```c++
int a(const int& b);
int a(      int& b);
```

The second overload is chosen because the first overload requires a `const`-qualification. The variable with which you called the function with, `c`, is non-`const`, so it is a perfect match for the *second overload* and can be bound to the non-`const` reference.

Answer (score 2):

```
int a(const int& b) {
    return b;
}
int a(int& b) {
    return b;
}

int main() {
    int c = a(4);
    a(c);
}
```

When you call it with `a(4)` 4 is a literal and only your version taking a `const reference` can bind it, so that's the one being called.

Now when you call `a(c)` you got `c` as a **non-const** `int` it will therefore prefer the function taking a **non-const** reference.